# Shouldn't this Mavericks question have remained open?

Tags: discussion

I resent you closed this issue [Finder windows won't show after reinstlling Mavericks ower Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135415/finder-windows-wont-show-after-reinstlling-mavericks-ower-yosemite)

How are we supposed to solve our Maverick related issues if we don't get to feedback on this env?

Answer (score 5):

We have chosen for several years now to not be a place to host answers about beta and pre-release OS from Apple.

Until such time as consensus
changes, you should find support on Yosemite issues from the vendor or on another site.

See the FAQ for Yosemite in specific: https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq

Comment: But for some weeks (?) Apple has changed its philosophy - everyone can now download the new Mac OS. It might be time to change this idea?

Comment: @Martin - no as the answers change as they do a new release and as the answers will be outdated when they do the full release the only place with useful info is the vendor's forums - if you can't get info from there don't run the beta

Comment: @Martin You could certainly open a new thread explaining how Apple's philosophy has changed (document if possible with specifics) or reply to the main question where the community has expressed a desire to not host these questions here. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712 and http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/

Comment: @Martin and include in that change https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq "don’t blog, post screen shots, tweet or publicly post information about the pre-release Apple software"